# Get two (Min) to work in one query in mysql

Tags: html, mysql, database

[Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2e00/15)

I want to retrieve the cheapest pre-owned and new prices for each product. This is the result I'm trying to get:

```
NAME    NEW_PRICE   NEW_MERCHANT    OLD_PRICE   OLD_MERCHANT
A852    1000        Amazon          200         BestBuy
T12h    NULL        NULL            300         BestBuy
```

Table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE price
    (`product_id` int,`price` int,`conditions` varchar(30),`merchant` varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO price
    (`product_id`,`price`,`conditions`,`merchant`)
VALUES
    (1,1000,'New','Amazon'),
    (1,200,'Old','BestBuy'),
    (1,1500,'New','Target'),
    (1,300,'Old','Amazon'),
    (2,600,'Old','Target'),
    (2,300,'Old','BestBuy')

;

CREATE TABLE product
    (`product_id` int,`name` varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO product
    (`product_id`,`name`)
VALUES
    (1,'A852'),
    (2,'T12h')

;
```

The following query could only fetch the first row of the result above. It wasn't able to get the record for `T12h` because there's no new price. And I also feel like there should be a better approach instead of repeating the subqueries in the `FROM clause` to match the prices and merchants for each product condition. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
SELECT a.name,a.New_price,a.New_merchant,
c.Old_price,c.Old_merchant
FROM
 (
  SELECT
   p.name,pr.product_id,MIN(pr.price) AS New_price,
   pr.merchant AS New_merchant
   FROM price pr
   INNER JOIN product p ON p.product_id = pr.product_id
   WHERE pr.conditions = 'NEW'
 )a 
 LEFT JOIN
 (
  SELECT product_id,MIN(price) AS new_price
    FROM price WHERE conditions = 'New'
 )b 
  ON a.new_price = b.new_price 
  AND a.product_id = b.product_id

 LEFT JOIN
  (
  SELECT
   p.name,pr.product_id,MIN(pr.price) AS Old_price,
   pr.merchant AS Old_merchant
   FROM price pr
   INNER JOIN product p ON p.product_id = pr.product_id
   WHERE pr.conditions = 'Old'
 )c ON c.product_id = a.product_id
  LEFT JOIN
 (
  SELECT product_id,MIN(price) AS Old_price
    FROM price WHERE conditions = 'Old'
 )d 
 ON c.Old_price = d.Old_price 
 AND c.product_id = d.product_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking at, first get the min price with `New` and min price with `Old` then `left join` them with the `product`

```
select
pr.*,
p1.price as new_price,
p1.merchant as new_merchant,
p2.price as old_price,
p2.merchant as old_merchant
from product pr
left join (
  select t1.* from price t1
  left join price t2 on t2.product_id = t1.product_id
  and t2.price < t1.price
  and t2.conditions = 'New'
  and t1.conditions = t2.conditions
  where t2.product_id is null and t1.conditions = 'New'
)p1
on p1.product_id = pr.product_id
left join
(
  select t1.* from price t1
  left join price t2 on t2.product_id = t1.product_id
  and t2.price < t1.price
  and t2.conditions = 'Old'
  and t1.conditions = t2.conditions
  where t2.product_id is null and t1.conditions = 'Old'
)p2
on p2.product_id = pr.product_id
;
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2e00/72)**